# Ext JS 4 - Grid instances sharing the same store

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I got a problem that is simply driving me insane. I created a window based widget that displays a grid. Ok, until now that is nothing special, but, each grid has to deal with different data. For Example: Imagine a homebroker, there is the widget that show the offers of a stock. So, the instance A has to show INTC, instance B has to show CSCO and instance C has to show FB. But when I deal with the data of INTC for instance A, the grids of instances B and C are updated too. So I understand that all grid a sharing the same store. 
I've already tried to create a store dinamically, but, it didn't work.

The question is, how do I do to separate this? There is another way to update a grid without stores?

Comment: Does this info help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12013880/531940

Comment: Perhaps post some code of how your grids and stores are defined, also which version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the store, you're probably declaring them like this:

```
{
     xtype: 'grid',
     store: 'theStore'
     // Rest of the properties
}
```

What you need to do is the following:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    //column definitions etc...
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var lStore = Ext.create('App.store.MyStore');

        Ext.apply(me, {
            store: lStore
        });

        me.callParent();
    }
}​
```

This creates a unique instance of the store, if you reference the store like this: store: 'MyStore' you just get the same store, and when you sort, page, filter, ... all the stores do the same.

Hope this helps you, since you didn't share any code.

Comment: Man, thanks for your effort, but still not working properly. I tried this way you posted, and I've been trying as many modifications I could think. Even when I create a new instance of a store, the results still the same: If I add or remove some item, all other grids reflect that.

Comment: Make sure you're not providing a storeId, and try using the bindStore method instead of just doing Ext.apply.

Comment: You should share some code then, we can't help you otherwise.